# Problemas ao me conectar ao sql server com Visual Studio e C#

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, visual-studio

Eu tenho encontrado problemas ao me conectar com o sql server pelo visual studio com o Entity Framework 6. A minha conexão funcionava normalmente e depois que criei um novo projeto, não consigo acesar o servidor do banco de dados.
O serviço funciona normalmente.

[image: Serviços do sql server ativos]

Minha string de conexão sempre está dando erro informando que a palavra chave Initial Catalog não é suportada. Já fiz a remoção deste parametro e percebi que tudo que está depois de Data Source é considerado como palavra chave não suportada.

```
public DataContext() : base("Data Source=localhost/sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=DocManager;User Id=sa;Password=123456; Integrated Security=false;")
    {

    }
```

O Firewall está desabilitado para evitar problemas de bloqueio de portas.

[image: Firewall Inativo]

Como alternativa eu tentei fazer a conexão pela ferramenta de gerenciador de servidores do próprio Visual Studio, mas pra minha decepção, não consigo fazer nenhuma conexão a partir dali e o meu servidor não é listado para conexão.

[image: Gerenciador de servidores não faz conexão]

Alguma sugestão que possa me ajudar a resolver este problema?

---

As exceções que eu recebo são estas:

1. Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog'.
2. Erro de rede ou específico à instância ao estabelecer conexão com o SQL Server. O servidor não foi encontrado ou não estava acessível. Verifique se o nome da instância está correto e se o SQL Server está configurado para permitir conexões remotas. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Não foi possível abrir uma conexão com o SQL Server)

No entanto o servidor está rodando. Já verifiquei o nome do servidor e tudo confere.

Comment: Quando você executa o projeto gera algum `exception`? Se sim, poderia adicionar ela na pergunta?

Comment: Keyword not supported: 'initial catalog'.
Erro de rede ou específico à instância ao estabelecer conexão com o SQL Server. O servidor não foi encontrado ou não estava acessível. Verifique se o nome da instância está correto e se o SQL Server está configurado para permitir conexões remotas. (provider: Named Pipes Provider, error: 40 - Não foi possível abrir uma conexão com o SQL Server)

Answer (score 1):

Na url `Data Source` use a a barra ao contrário `\`.

```
// Nào esqueça de usar a sequencia de escape \\
public DataContext() : base("Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DocManager;User Id=sa;Password=123456; Integrated Security=false;")
{

}
```

Answer (score -2):

Eu removi os dados de login e deixei a Integrated Security como true e ele operou normalmente(como é só ambiente de teste eu deixei como true):

---

```sql
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder) //Método de configuração do Entity, nos informa qual banco de dados usaremos
        {
            //String de conexão
            optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("Data Source=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=DocManager;Integrated Security=true");
        }
```